# How can I create my authorship markup on a page that I’m going to syndicate on other sites?

Tags: duplicate-content, rich-snippets, author, google-authorship

In an interview Google Web Spam Team Head Matt Cutts stated that

**“Syndication can be a valid way to either increase your reputation or to drive traffic and potentially to get more links. The main caution that I would add is that there are some mechanical things that you should pay attention to and try to make sure that you get right.”**

He also stated that 
**“Things like rel=canonical help. Embedding a link within the text of the article itself never hurts. Ideally, you’d want to insist on some sort of attribution on the syndicated page. You can use authorship markup. So if you are also publishing the article on your site, you want to try and do these mechanical things so you are still seen as the original author.”**

I know how to use rel=canonical in a page and also to create an authorship markup for a website but I don’t know how to create authorship markup for a webpage that I want to syndicate to other sites?

Does publishing content of our webpage into others sites by only indicating Authors name and website is enough for authorship markup?

For more information related to that interview visit : http://www.stonetemple.com/link-building-is-not-illegal-or-bad/

See the below image
[image: Matt Cutts interview about Link Building]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have an email address on the domain of the sites you're syndicating to, embed a link to your Google+ profile in the article (remembering to add `?rel=author` to URL), and add the syndicating site under the "Contributor to" section of your Google+ profile, as per [Option 2 on Google's help page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986?hl=en).

I suspect a problem you might have with this is that you may not know or be able to track all sites which are publishing the content, and so be unable to add the Contributor link. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way around that.

Comment: I find it strange that google does not have a submit system for content authors, since google knows duplicates, it could reduce plagiarism to a bare minimum